# Auto Suggest Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, autocomplete, autosuggest

Is there a JavaScript library that allows me to do the following:

- An auto suggest dropdownlist that does an Ajax call to database to
  get the results.
- The user is only able to select values
     returned from the Ajax call.
- I want to format the data results
     so I can show multiple columns.

Ex.  User types in an address and it returns
address_id,
street (10 Lincoln Ave),
city,
state and
zipcode

I wanted to do a auto suggest textbox, but that does not restrict the user from entering values that are not returned from the Ajax call.

Thank you,
-Tesh

Comment: You'll get a lot farther with this if you break your requirements up into logical pieces.  To start with, there is no reason why the dropdown library needs to do the AJAX call.  Many don't, and there is no reason for them to.  Leave that up to your own code.

Comment: Sorry Brad.  The reason, as stated above was that the user can only select valid responses from the Ajax call.  Because I need to save address_id.  Is there a way to force the user to select only valid responses from a auto-suggest textbox? Maybe I am going down the wrong path by using a dropdownlist.

Comment: I think you're missing the point a bit.  I'm not saying don't use AJAX... I'm saying, don't look for an all-in-one magic solution.  There are plenty of autocompleter type jQuery pluings out there.  A good one comes with jQuery UI.  Many of these plugins available leave the data sourcing up to you... as they should!  That gives you the opportunity to write code to get data, and handle it how you want.

Comment: My intention was to find out if anything was out there first.  I looked and did not find anything.  Just wanted to try this site, before I do what you and Sidharth suggested below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at jQueryUI autocomplete. It does the first 2, but you can customize it to get the 3rd requirement too.